# Higher-order and black-box clustering

Tags: reference-request, machine-learning, clustering

As far as I understand a large number of clustering problems can be formulated as:

$\underset{\textbf{P}}{ \text{argmin}} \;  \sum_{i,j} f \left(x_i, x_j\right)$

where $\textbf{P}$ is a partitioning of $\mathbf{x}$. In other words, the goal is to find a partitioning that is optimal with respect to a sum of pairwise contributions of the variables within and/or across clusters. Problems such as K-means and [correlation clustering](http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1170&context=compsci) can be written in the above form. For example, K-means minimizes the sum-of-squares which [is known](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1519389) to be NP-hard.

I am wondering if there is any work on what I informally would call **higher-order** or clustering, where the functions $f$ measure the affinity of general cliques of variables

$\underset{\textbf{P}}{\text{argmax}}\; \sum_{c_i} f(\mathbf{x}_{c_i})$

for cliques $c_i$ in some set $C$.

Perhaps a more difficult problem is what I would informally call **black-box** clustering, i.e. problems of the above form where $f$ is **unknown** (i.e. we don't have access to an algebraic or analytical expression of $f$, but we can **query it**. I imagine using some sort of [direct-search optimization](http://www.cs.wm.edu/~va/research/sirev.pdf) method for solving such problems.

Does anybody know of if these problems have been addressed in the literature? Perhaps they are known by other names?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for spatial index or space-fillin-curve?

Comment: Since your sum is "within and across clusters", I don't see where $\mathbf{P}$ comes in.

Comment: Thanks @RickyDemer, $\textbf{P}$ is encoded in the choice of the variables $x_i$. That said, in K-means for example we only look for contributions within clusters.

Answer (score 2):

One example of what you might call non-linear clustering is kernel-based clustering, where the similarity function is described by a (non-linear) kernel function. This is a weak form of non-linearity, since there's a lifting map that makes everything linear (albeit in a Hilbert space)

Comment: Thanks @Suresh, but everything I have seen on kernel-based clustering seems to be linear (maybe also quadratic?) in pairwise contributions between variables. The function $f$ above can measure the affinity of a clique of any size. I will clarify this in the question.

Comment: ah I see what you mean.